# Auto Refresh Pivot Table Excel for select cells

Tags: excel

Good afternoon,

Problem:  I have a pivot table that does not auto refresh when the cells its referencing changes values. So the values change in B2:B200, but the pivot table values do not change with it.

A friend of mine provided me with some code and its not working, so I'll share.

```
    Public Sub RecalculateSelection()
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Application.Selection
        rng.Calculate
    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just use `Sheets("YourSheetName").PivotTables.Update` or if you have a lot pivots on the sheet `Sheets("YourSheetName").PivotTables("YourPivotsName").Update`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

If you want the pivot table to update when you change values in the cells without having to hit the Pivot Table refresh button in the ribbon, you could trigger a `pivottable.update` from the worksheet's `_Change()` event.

In your VBE (Alt+F11) double click on the worksheet that contains the data that drives the pivot table in the VBAProject.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'change range for which we are detecting a change in this line
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B200")) Is Nothing Then
        'Update Pivottables in a specific worksheet:
        Sheets("YourPivotsWorksheetName").PivotTables.Update
    End If
End Sub
```

Now if you change a cell in `B2:B200` the pivot tables in the tab "YourPivotsWorksheetName" will be updated.

### Updated to work across changes in multiple sheets

If the ranges that you might physically change are across multiple sheets you can use the `Workbook_SheetChange()` event. You'll have to do this in the `ThisWorkbook` portion of your VBAProject.

`Workbook_SheetChange()` comes with two parameters. `sh` is the worksheet that triggered the change, and `Target` is the Range in which the change took place.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'Detect changes only in these sheets
    If instr(1, "Sheet1,Sheet2,Some Other Worksheet", sh.name) Then
        'Detect changes in only this range - Feel free to remove this IF
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B200")) Is Nothing Then
            'Update Pivottables in a specific worksheet:
            Sheets("YourPivotsWorksheetName").PivotTables.Update
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Using that as a starting point you can see how to detect changes only in specific worksheets and only specific ranges.

Comment: According to MS on worksheet_change, "This event does not occur when cells change during a recalculation."

Comment: Then change the `WorkSheet_Change` routine to the worksheet where the cells are changing. You are changing something to cause the range to which the pivot points to change, so point this code at that action so your pivot will refresh. If it's more than one sheet that might trigger a recalc, then you can use the workbook's `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` event.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I changed WorkSheet_Change to the command provided. My pivot tables are still not updating when the data it is referencing is calculated. Thanks.

Comment: I've added the code and some explanation of how to use it to the answer.